# Semantic UI Merge row

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I would like to have this grid on my page

[image: grid]

1 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 should have the same size and '2' should be height*2 and width*2 of the smaller boxes

I cannot make this "2" box

All this grid should fit the remaining height thus I cannot fix a width/height

**CODE**

```css
.box {
  border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui stackable three column grid contentGrid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column box">a</div>
      <div class="two column box">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column box">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column box">d</div>
      <div class="column box">e</div>
      <div class="column box">f</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give all the small boxes a 33% width and height and the bigger box a 67% width and height. Also bootstrap is good at this sort of stuff if you're open to using it (and plan on doing more of this kind of thing is your site).

Comment: I would prefer to keep Semantic UI - And give this height and width is not the answer I was waiting for

Comment: Bootstrap columns works in factors of 12 so you could have 2 `<div class="col-xs-3>` and one `<div class="col-xs-6>` (and set the height in regular css or sass) and then set all the bottom ones as `<div class="col-xs-3>`. These links are good reading for bootstrap http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Oh sorry the comment has changes, fair enough, I can't see a way to do it with it (from a quick look)

Comment: Any idea how to do it with Semantic UI ?

Comment: Updated my comment as well. No sorry, I've never used it but it looks possible with this http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Comment: I have already look at this but there is no similar example

Comment: I think the top 3 should be in the one row so you should only need two rows. Then the bigger box should push the other two to the left, seems to be the only way to do it

Comment: And then for the 2 box in one, how can I splitted them so they can have the same height than others ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in that framework I think it'll have to be done with css, most front end frameworks are only really concerned with width as that's the main problem point with trying to make a responsive site etc

Answer (score 0):

You can center your grid and divide 15 parts into three, leaving one part out.

Then use two rows.
The first row will be split 1:2 and the second row will be split equally in three parts.

What I do is that in the left column in the first row, I make two sixteen wide columns, that automatically appear one below the other (since the grid is 16 wide)

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/vot63seu/

```
<div class="ui unstackable centered padded grid contentGrid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="five wide column no-padding ">
        <div class="sixteen wide column box">
        a
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide column box">
        b
        </div>      
        </div>
      <div class="ten wide column box">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="five wide column box">d</div>
      <div class="five wide column box">e</div>
      <div class="five wide column box">f</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issue you will have to resolve manually using CSS is the `.row` and `.column` **padding** and **margin** properties.

Also, this only works if you keep your grid `unstackable`. 
Otherwise box 1 and 3 do not stack as expected